# Убрать выделение изображения-ссылки при нажатии

Tags: html, css

Нужно, чтобы картинка не выделялась при нажатии на мобильных устройствах. Как, например, яблоко на apple.com.

Answer (score 3):

Выделение текста для дальнейшего копирования:

```
.text {
  user-select: none;
}
```

Нажатие на ссылку (outline)

```
.link {
  outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если под словом "выделение" вы подразумеваете вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть выделение как у текста, то есть вот такой трюк

```css
.no-select {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="no-select">
  <h3>Этот текст нельзя выделить</h3>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSGmD.png" width="200" border="2">
  <p>Картинку тоже</p>
</div>
```

Правда не знаю насколько этот трюк кроссбраузерный, ибо не тестировал.